# Unable to display an Image from database using Struts2

Tags: image, jsp, struts2

I am trying to display an image from a directory, but It is not getting displayed.

What I have done ?
I have uploaded in image and saved into a directory then I have saved the path of this directory and Image name in database.

What is the problem ?
When I am trying to display the image by fetching the path & image name from database and trying to render it on a jsp using `<img src="${imagePath}"/>`. I see a broken image.

When I do <kbd>F12</kbd> and copy the link for that `src` property and paste it into the browser, I am able to see the image.

Please let me know, how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Add the url. If it's relative, you're probably adding a leading / that should not be there.

Comment: Hi, Yeah found it yesterday. I was using the absolute path earlier and then replaced it by relative path. It did work. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem now. I changed my absolute path to relative path and images started popping up.

Thanks to all for the help !!!